# How to convert tail light to LED?

Tags: led, resistors, lamp

I want to convert my tail light(Peugeot 405) to LED light.there are 5 lamp in this case.

Instead of each lamp I think 6 white LEDs are enough. as you know better than me, each white LED is 3.3v and 20mA, so it is my circuit diagram for that :

[image]

So my questions are:

1) Is this circuit diagram correct ?

2) How many LEDs are you suggest for each lamp ?

3) Is it better parallel all LEDs together and at the end I calculate a resistor or like I draw instead of 3 LEDs I put 120Ohm resistor.

At the end it would be great if you have a video or pictures for that step by step.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I do not recommend this, plain LEDs are not bright enough. How will you know if the lights meet the standard in your country? You could be breaking the law, or cause an accident because someone couldn't see your lights.

Comment: thnx for your reply, if law confirm that, may I ask your opinion about diagram and electronic stuffs ?

Comment: The voltage drop on LEDs varies, you will need to post a link to the specification for the LED that you want to use. This site does not recommend components, so if you ask for a recommendation, your question will probably be closed.

Comment: Your circuit is correct for making 6 LEDs light up with around 20 mA of current per LED. Look at the LED tail lights of cars you can buy. I'm guessing that they have maybe 20 to 50 LEDs in there. And those wouldn't be your average type of LED, they would be high efficiency ones. Also a tail light is usually red, using white LEDs is then inefficient as only the red part of the spectrum will be visible. I would suggest using red LEDs. I agree with other comments that experimenting with your car's lights isn't a good idea.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, white LEDs behind a red filter will not only be inefficient like you said, they might even turn out a different color (purple-ish) depending on the spectrum of the LEDs and the filter. Red LEDs would be much better. I also agree that it’s not wise to experiment.

Comment: This is the correct configuration. I'd recommend 1 resistor per series string. For the brightness I think you will have to try it and see. If you have the lumen output for the tail light bulb and the leds, you could match the two and see how that looks?

Comment: @Drew thnx for your reply may I ask you to show me your diagram ? I couldn't catch you

Comment: Your diagram is OK - resisto value may need altering **BUT** what StarCat says is VERY important. Most white L:EDS use a deep blue LED pkus yellow phosphor - the two combine to produce white. They do NOT have very much Red component. Using a red filter will remove most of the blue and yellow light and the red will not be very bright. Using red LEDs will be MUCH better. As red LEDs have Vf ~= 2V you can use 4 or 5 in series plus a resistor from 12V.

Comment: @Mattman944 ~= 6 x 20 mA x 3V ~= 360 mW. Or about the equivalent of about a 4W incandescent bulb. With the LED focused to say typically 14 degrees the light will be as good or better than a std 12V 5W bulb. At say 100 l/W that's about 36 lumen. Shine that out via a say 100mm x 100mm lens (larger than likely) and you get around 36l/(0.1m x 0.1m) ~= 3500 lux - nice and bright.

Answer (score 2):

You start with the typical voltage drop at the recommended current.

[image]

12V = 2.1V * 3LEDs + 20mA * R

Solve for R, R = 285 ohms

Then see how much current you get at the maximum voltage drop.

12V = 2.6V * 3LEDs + i * 285

Solve for i, i = 14.7 mA

This is probably OK, if it was much lower, you might want to reconsider and only put 2 LEDs in series. This is assuming that high brightness is important.

I haven't considered that your battery voltage is not a constant 12V. If it is 14V while the engine is running:

14V = 2.1V * 3LEDs + i * 285

Solve for i, i = 27.0 mA

This is still within the manufactures recommended LED current of 10 to 30 mA.

Note that this is only an example, you need to use the specifications for the LED that you have chosen.

And this is all hypothetical, as I said in my comment, I don't recommend altering your car.

Comment: thnx for your reply - rep ++

Answer (score 2):

Your diagram is OK - resistor value may need altering.

However, what StarCat says is VERY important.
Most white LEDS use a deep blue LED plus yellow phosphor - the two combine to produce white. They do NOT have very much red component.
Using a red filter will remove most of the blue and yellow light and the red will not be very bright.
**Using red LEDs will be MUCH better.**
As red LEDs have Vf (forward voltage) ~= 2V you can use 4 or 5 in series plus a resistor from 12V.

If using say 10 red LEDS (2 x 5) at 2V each at 20 mA and 100 l/W (typical).
10 x 20 mA x 2V ~= 400 mW.
Or about the equivalent of about a 4 or 5 W incandescent bulb.
With the LED focused to say typically 14 degrees the light will be as good or better than a std 12V 5W bulb. At say 100 l/W that's about 40 lumen.
Shine that out via a say 100mm x 100mm lens (larger than likely) and you get around
40 l/(0.1m x 0.1m) ~= 4000 lux = nice and bright

Comment: thnx for your reply, may I ask you to draw final diagram for both situation (white and red), rep ++

Comment: @Freeman White is a VERY BAD choice, as I explained. || For red I suggested 2 x 5 and said your diagram was OK. I leave you to convert that to reality. || For 5 red LEDs in series,  12v, 20 mA, Vf = ?: R = V/I = (12V - (5 x Vf)) / 0.020 A